# Sobre singleton pattern em Dart, como entender essa estrutura?

Tags: dart, singleton

```dart
ContactHelper.internal();

static final ContactHelper _instance = ContactHelper.internal();

factory ContactHelper() => _instance;
```

Depois de uma intensa pesquisa sobre factory methods e singleton pattern, consegui entender o objetivo dessas padronizações, mas não consigo entender o funcionamento do código acima feito em Dart. Não consigo assimilar uma ordem de acontecimentos, como ele referencia a própria instância já criada ou não, afinal é isso mesmo que acontece?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiramente vamos deixar alguns pontos esclarecidos sobre esta pergunta:

- **Construtores Privados**

Em Dart podemos definir construtores privados através do modificador `_` como prefixo. Existe uma convensão natural de nomeação desse construtor como `_internal()` mas na verdade ele pode ser `_qualquerNome()`, ou até apenas `_()`
Esse construtor definido como privado é acessível apenas dentro da propria classe, ou lib que ela pertence.

- **Construtores Factory**

Essa keyword é utilizada na criação de construtores que nem sempre criam uma nova instância da classe, podendo ao invés disso, retornar uma instância de um cache previamente criada, ou nesse caso uma única instância utilizada no padrão Singleton. Por exemplo:

```dart
class Pessoa {
  final String nome;
  
  Pessoa._internal(this.nome);
  
  static final Map<String, Pessoa> _cachePessoas = {};
  
  factory Pessoa(String nome) {
    if(_cachePessoas.containsKey(nome)) {
      return _cachePessoas[nome];
    }
    
    final novaPessoa = Pessoa._internal(nome);
    _cachePessoas[nome] = novaPessoa;
    return novaPessoa;
  }
  
  static imprimirCache() {
    print(_cachePessoas);
  }
}

void main() {
  Pessoa('Elon Musk');
  Pessoa('Bill Gates');
  Pessoa('Elon Musk');
  Pessoa('Bill Gates');

  Pessoa.imprimirCache();  
}
```

Acima de forma simples notamos o funcionamento do factory em conjunto com um construtor privado para recuperar objetos de um cache de pessoas, e ao chamar o mesmo construtor a segunda vez para a mesma pessoa, não é criada uma nova instância e sim retornado uma existente. [Teste no Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6dac20ca16be89b16a360ab14fd8129a).

- **Singletons em Dart**

Existem algumas formas de criação de um Singleton em Dart, onde não há melhor ou pior.

1. Singleton com Factory - [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/011d709797b78286abfc52d0237e7aa6)

```dart
class Pessoa {
  Pessoa._();

  static final Pessoa _instance = Pessoa._();

  factory Pessoa(){
    return _instance;
  }
}

main () {
  Pessoa um = Pessoa();
  Pessoa dois = Pessoa();
  print(identical(um, dois));
}
```

Esse é o exemplo que você usou, utiliza um construtor factory e outro privado para garantir que haverá apenas uma instância da classe Pessoa.
O que está acontecendo é que:

> Nossa `_instance` é static, por isso ela pertence a classe, não ao objeto.
>
> Como é um membro da classe, com o final, indicamos que ela deve ser inicializada, por isso inicializamos através do construtor privado `_()`
>
> O final também garante que esse valor não irá sofrer modificações durante a execução do programa, tendo assim o nosso Singleton garantido.
>
> Com isso, ao chamar `Pessoa()`, apenas retornamos a instância previamente criada, garantindo que sempre será a mesma.

Note que quem chama essa classe não sabe se a mesma é ou não um Singleton, pois está apenas chamando `Pessoa()` que poderia estar criando sempre uma nova instância normalmante. Portanto essa abordagem pode ser utilizada quando você não quer que quem utilize saiba que é um Singleton, ou até mesmo tem a intenção de futuramente alterar essa implementação para deixar de ser um Singleton sem quebrar o código de quem a chama.

2. Singleton com get - [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/465d6cc65ee8e203acffff67206d2fca)

```dart
class Pessoa {
  Pessoa._();

  static final Pessoa _instance = Pessoa._();

  static Pessoa get instance { return _instance;}
}

main () {
  Pessoa um = Pessoa.instance;
  Pessoa dois = Pessoa.instance;
  print(identical(um, dois));
}
```

Uma outra abordagem similar a anterior porém sem o factory, agora estamos acessando a instância através de um get, dessa forma quem utiliza nosso Singleton sabe explicitamente que ele é um Singleton. Nosso construtor privado novamente garante que não haverá outra forma de instanciar uma nova Pessoa, onde a única alternativa é a utilização da instância que a gente disponibiliza.

3. Singleton com membro static - [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1f8ed681a0e17f2bfa1341d75c128271)

```dart
class Pessoa {
  Pessoa._();

  static final Pessoa instance = Pessoa._();
}

main () {
  Pessoa um = Pessoa.instance;
  Pessoa dois = Pessoa.instance;
  print(identical(um, dois));
}
```

Com uma pequena alteração na abordagem anterior, temos uma nova forma mais curta. A única diferença é que agora nossa instância não é mais privada, podendo ser acessada diretamente sem a necessidade de um get.
É a que exige menos linhas de código, porém, é a única que não permite que seja feito algo caso sempre antes de que alguém acesse nossa instância.

Está respondido? (:

Comment: Bem explicado, agradeço a sua resposta, só ficou uma dúvida quanto a esta última forma de criar um Singleton, mais especificamente quando você diz "é a única que não permite que seja feito algo caso sempre antes de que alguém acesse nossa instância", pelo que consegui entender, ela não nos permite inicializa-la com validações ou métodos anteriores, estou correto?

Comment: @jsdaniell Imagine que você quer contar quantas vezes a instância é chamada (ou fazer qualquer outra coisa). No primeiro você pode aumentar o count no construtor factory, no segundo pode aumentar no get, já no terceiro não é possível pois a instância é acessada diretamente.